# I'm not using dependency injection, but I'm getting "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type"

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

I've seen lots of answers about how improper use of dependency injection can cause the error...

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'FranchiseUserController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

but I am not using any dependency injection products like Ninject, Unity, etc.
 Also, this error does not happen in my local development environment, but is showing up when we are testing on our QA server. Furthermore, it occurs intermittently and it occurs with several of my Web API methods. It occurs with multiple users and with multiple browsers.

I'm not sure what code to even post here. Let me know if you need more information and I will be glad to post it.

This is an ASP.NET MVC / WebAPI application using AngularJS. The error occurs when calling the Web API controller from an Angular client. The angular app is receiving a response in the Error callback with a 500 Internal Server Error with...

> Data Exception Message: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'FranchiseUserController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
>       Data Exception Type: System.InvalidOperationException

Here is the constructor from the controller that is mentioned in the error and the method that was being called.

The constructor

```
public FranchiseUserController()
{
    _sm = new SettingManager();
    _millicare_connectionString = _sm.conn_MilliCareSvcConnectionString();
    _maa_connectionString = _sm.conn_MaaSvcConnectionString();

    if (AppConstants.OverrideSecurityLocal && _sm.ServiceConfiguration() == ServiceConfigurationValues.LOCAL)
    {
        _acsUser.Name = Environment.UserName;
        _acsUser.MaaUserGuid = _sm.developerAdGuid().ConvertAdGuidToMaaGuid();
        _acsUser.Role = _sm.app_TestUserRole();
    }
    else {
        ClaimsPrincipal userClaims = (ClaimsPrincipal)this.User;
        _acsUser.Name = ((ClaimsIdentity)userClaims.Identity).FindFirst(MiddlewareClaimTypes.Name).Value;
        _acsUser.MaaUserGuid = ((ClaimsIdentity)userClaims.Identity).FindFirst(MiddlewareClaimTypes.MaaUserGuid).Value;
        _acsUser.Role = AppConstants.RoleNotAuthorized;

        //Get user role
        if (ApplicationMiddleware.Security.Extensions.HasClaim(userClaims, AppConstants.Maint_Option, AppConstants.Maint_Action, AppConstants.Maint_SecureValue_Approver, _sm.acs_MAAFranchiseResourceMaint()))
        {
            _acsUser.Role = AppConstants.RoleApprover;
        }
        else if (ApplicationMiddleware.Security.Extensions.HasClaim(userClaims, AppConstants.Maint_Option, AppConstants.Maint_Action, AppConstants.Maint_SecureValue_Admin, _sm.acs_MAAFranchiseResourceMaint()))
        {
            _acsUser.Role = AppConstants.RoleAdmin;
        }
        else if (ApplicationMiddleware.Security.Extensions.HasClaim(userClaims, AppConstants.Resource_Option, AppConstants.Resource_Action, AppConstants.Resource_SecureValue_Franchise, _sm.acs_MAAFranchiseResourceReports()))
        {
            _acsUser.Role = AppConstants.RoleFranchise;
        }
    }
}
```

...and the method

```
[ValidateCustomAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateAddress(Address_dto Value)
{
    HttpResponseMessage srvresponse = new HttpResponseMessage();

    if (_acsUser.Role == AppConstants.RoleAdmin || _acsUser.Role == AppConstants.RoleApprover)
    {
        Value.modified_user = _acsUser.Name;
        srvresponse = WrapServiceCall<string>((serviceResult, responseMessage) =>
        {
            MilliCareSvcClient().Using(svc =>
            {
                serviceResult.OperationSuccessful = svc.UpdateAddress(Value);
            });
        });
        return srvresponse;
    }
    else
    {
        var noaccessServiceResult = new ServiceResult<string>();
        noaccessServiceResult.SetUnauthorizedMessage();
        srvresponse.Content = new ObjectContent<ServiceResult<string>>(noaccessServiceResult, new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        return srvresponse;
    }
    //});
}
```

Comment: You have no other constructors on that class? If so, sounds like a bug in the framework to me.

Comment: No, that's it. Any workarounds?

Comment: The answer is weird but see if that helps since you said it si only QA environment. http://forums.asp.net/t/2027017.aspx?Web+API+2+0+An+error+occurred+when+trying+to+create+a+controller+of+type+

Comment: @Gomes Thanks, but that article appears to be addressing a repeatable error. My error doesn't occur every time, so I don't think it's a database value error.

Comment: @JohnWay what i am saying is the error is very generic and reason could be a lot. For your scenario it could be an runtime business logic issue. I would recommend put a error and capture at global.asax level and see if that helps. All the best

Comment: @Gomes No, that error isn't very generic. It's thrown by the framework when it's instantiating instances of controllers and it can't find a parameterless constructor and there's no DI container wired up to fulfill parameters of non-parameterless constructors.

Comment: DI has nothing to do with this - framework discovers and instantiates your controllers. Try moving all class initialization logic in constructor(s) (you have a few member initializations), then use try/catch and log any errors - it's probably something environment-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you have code in your controller constructor that accesses the `HttpControllerContext` in some way. You may be running into situations where the `HttpControllerContext` is not ready before the controller is created (perhaps during an application pool restart).

It is best to [keep your controller constructors simple](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/), since they may be created at any point during the lifecycle of the application. If you were using DI, I would suggest to move your complex logic into a service and don't do anything in the constructors except assign services. However, since you are not using DI, you could potentially fix this issue by moving your logic into the `Initialize` event of your controller, and removing the constructor entirely.

```
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
    base.Initialize(controllerContext);

    _sm = new SettingManager();
    _millicare_connectionString = _sm.conn_MilliCareSvcConnectionString();
    _maa_connectionString = _sm.conn_MaaSvcConnectionString();

    if (AppConstants.OverrideSecurityLocal && _sm.ServiceConfiguration() == ServiceConfigurationValues.LOCAL)
    {
        _acsUser.Name = Environment.UserName;
        _acsUser.MaaUserGuid = _sm.developerAdGuid().ConvertAdGuidToMaaGuid();
        _acsUser.Role = _sm.app_TestUserRole();
    }
    else
    {
        ClaimsPrincipal userClaims = (ClaimsPrincipal)this.User;
        _acsUser.Name = ((ClaimsIdentity)userClaims.Identity).FindFirst(MiddlewareClaimTypes.Name).Value;
        _acsUser.MaaUserGuid = ((ClaimsIdentity)userClaims.Identity).FindFirst(MiddlewareClaimTypes.MaaUserGuid).Value;
        _acsUser.Role = AppConstants.RoleNotAuthorized;

        //Get user role
        if (ApplicationMiddleware.Security.Extensions.HasClaim(userClaims, AppConstants.Maint_Option, AppConstants.Maint_Action, AppConstants.Maint_SecureValue_Approver, _sm.acs_MAAFranchiseResourceMaint()))
        {
            _acsUser.Role = AppConstants.RoleApprover;
        }
        else if (ApplicationMiddleware.Security.Extensions.HasClaim(userClaims, AppConstants.Maint_Option, AppConstants.Maint_Action, AppConstants.Maint_SecureValue_Admin, _sm.acs_MAAFranchiseResourceMaint()))
        {
            _acsUser.Role = AppConstants.RoleAdmin;
        }
        else if (ApplicationMiddleware.Security.Extensions.HasClaim(userClaims, AppConstants.Resource_Option, AppConstants.Resource_Action, AppConstants.Resource_SecureValue_Franchise, _sm.acs_MAAFranchiseResourceReports()))
        {
            _acsUser.Role = AppConstants.RoleFranchise;
        }
    }
}
```

> **NOTE:** I cannot say for certain this is what is happening in your application, however you should *always* assume there is no HTTP Context available at the time a controller is instantiated.

On a side note, this logic looks like a cross-cutting concern. You should be doing it in a [filter](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2988903/application-architecture/how-to-secure-web-api-using-authorization-filters.html), not repeating it in every controller.

Comment: This answer allowed me to capture the real error, which was that the claims in the userClaims.Identity were gone. They had been cleared out due to a session timeout.